# app.config entries required in website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have a Visual Stuido 2010 website project (not web application). I need to provide the ability to make a web service call, either ad-hoc from a website button or scheduled. So I create a c# library containing a WCF call to the target web service. I then add a reference to my library from the website. I am now able to call a public method on my library that then call the webservice - great!

My problem is, the website seems to insist on having the system.servicemodel web.config entries required for the call to the web service. Although this works, it means I have two places to maintain them - in the web.config of the client website and the app.config of my c# library. I have also created a c# console application (to trigger the web service call on a schedule) which references the library app, this too requires a copy system.servicemodel entries in its app.config. The same applies for connection strings.

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to avoid this reliance on having duplicate web.config / app.config entries spread through various projects of the solution?

Thanks,Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "externalize" your relevant config sections into separate files, and reference those from both `app.config` as well as your `web.config`.

Any .NET configuration section can be stashed into an external config file, so you can write:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings configSource="bindings.config" />
  <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config" />
  <client configSource="client.config" /> 
  ....
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now, your external files will look exactly like the relevant config section inside your config:

`bindings.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" />
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="......."  ...... />
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Note: Visual Studio's editor will complain about the `configSource=` attribute - but the Intellisense is mixed up - the `configSource` attribute **is** present on each configuration section, and **it does work** just fine!

Note #2: you cannot externalize the entire `<system.serviceModel>` since that is a **configuration  section group** - and those do not have any means to be put into external files, unfortunately.

Comment: @MitchWheat: guess we'll have to pester the .NET teams ;-)